# Cannot do anything on Elementary OS due to disk being full

Tags: disk-usage

My disk became full without me noticing it so I was unable to react. Now when I come to the login screen it loops and I assume this is due to the disk being full.

Pressing ctrl + alt + f1 gets me down to the command line. However I can't even rm -f anything because I get this error

`-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device`

I don't know what to do next? How can I delete anything to get back in my system?

Comment: please add output of `df -h` if that works.

Comment: You get that error when running `rm`, or instead of your prompt? In the former case, maybe you have some alias that tries to implement "recycle bin" functionality, you could try using `/bin/rm` explicitly.

Comment: I'm guessing that error appears when you use tab-completion and not while running `rm`, right?

Comment: I wanted to suggest the same as @Panki, from my experience this happens with tab-completion and full disk. Try to list files (with sizes) without tab-comletion `ls -lh /some/dir` and remove respective files the same way. I would look into `/var/log/` first and maybe truncate some files (e.g. `truncate -s0 /some/large/file`) without removing them so you don't interrupt system services.

Answer (score 0):

Boot the PC from a [LiveUSB](https://www.lifewire.com/create-elementary-os-live-usb-drive-2202054), access your primary drive, and then either delete files you don't need, or move files off to another storage device.

After you have solved the immediate issue, then you may wish to consider a method to monitor space available on a regular basis, perhaps with a tool like [tmpreaper](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/tmpreaper.8.html) which can be configured to purge files older than *x* days in specific directories.